# Clarification on limits arithmetics

Tags: real-analysis

Given a limit in the form of: $\lim_{x \to \infty} ((1+\frac{1}{f(x)})^{f(x)})^{g(x)}$

Assuming we know $f(x)\xrightarrow[x \to \infty]{}\infty, g(x)\xrightarrow[x \to \infty]{}c \in \mathbb{R}$

Why is it true that the limit is $e^c$? or isn't it?

This is just a little thing I'm trying to understand, not h.w or something.

I'm looking for a formal explanation obviously so $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{f(x)})^{f(x)}=e$ is obvious and not an answer.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure if I'm qualified enough to answer your question. Nonetheless, doesn't what you are asking simply boil down to the following question: 

Suppose $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {a_n} =A \text{ and } \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {b_n} = B$

Is it the case that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {a_n}^{b_n} = A^B $$

I'm not sure if this is true but I would guess yes given that ${a_n}^{b_n} = \exp\left(b_n \ln[a_n] \right) $ and the exponentiation function is continuous.

Comment: @AnlamK Thank you, I think this answers my question.

Comment: @AnlamK  You have to be careful in that situation. There are problems if $A<0.$ What does $(-1)^{1/2}$ even mean? And if $A,B$ are both $0,$ then the answer is $0^0?$ What is $0^0?.$

Comment: @zhw Thanks. There could be some other exceptions as well - for instance even if you use complex numbers, there might be cases where you are just circling around the unit disk for instance. (Again, I'm not sure of this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u(x)\to e$ and $v(x)\to c,$ then $u(x)^{v(x)} \to e^c.$

Proof: Apply $\ln$ to the expression to get $v(x)\cdot \ln u(x).$ Note $\ln u(x)\to \ln e =1.$ By the product rule for limits, $v(x)\cdot \ln u(x)\to c\cdot 1 = c.$ Exponentiating back gives $e^c$ for the original limit.

So in your problem all you need to verify is that $(1+1/f(x))^{f(x)} \to e,$ which is pretty standard.

Comment: Can we use laws of equations in limits? I mean something like this 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} (f(x)) ^{g(x)} = y \\   \lim_{x\to 0} g(x) ln (f(x)) = ln(y) \\   \lim_{x\to 0 } ln(f(x)) = ln(y)/g(x)
$$

Comment: Your third line is incorrect because $g(x)$ is varying with $x.$

Comment: So, I cannot take it to RHS? Or is there a possibility that $g(x)$ may go to zero as $x$ goes to zero?

Comment: You can't take it to the RHS and just leave it there; there should be no $x$ at all in the end. You are taking a limit as $x\to 0.$

Comment: Thank you so much.